# Count characters in a multidimensional array, Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, counter

Below is my code:

```
public int maxTurns = 0;
public String[][] bombBoard = new String[9][9];

...

public void loadBombs()
{
    //loadArray();
    Random randomGen = new Random();
    for (int u=1; u<=9; u++)
    {
        int randomRow = randomGen.nextInt(9);
        int randomCol= randomGen.nextInt(9);
        bombBoard[randomRow][randomCol] = "@";
    }

    //counting @'s -- setting variable
    for (int d = 0; d < bombBoard[bombRow].length; d++)
    {
        for (int e = 0; e < bombBoard[bombCol].length; e++)
        {
            if (bombBoard[d].equals("@") || bombBoard[e].equals("@"))
            {
                maxTurns++;
            }
        }
    }
```

All I want to do is count the amount of (@)'s in the multidimensional array and assign it to a variable called maxTurns.

Probably very simple, just having a super hard time with it tonight. Too much time away from Java >.<

Answer (score 2):

This line is equating the character `@` with the entire `dth` row or `eth` row. Does not make sense really because an array row cannot equal to a single character.

```
if (bombBoard[d].equals("@") || bombBoard[e].equals("@"))
```

Instead, access a single cell like this

```
if (bombBoard[d][e].equals("@"))
```

And initialize `maxTurns` before counting i.e. before your for loop:

```
maxTurns = 0;
```

Comment: Isn't the first line `public int maxTurns = 0;` initializing it?

Comment: Oh I missed that, but make sure before counting it _must_ be zero, not changed by any other ways (e.g. in another method or even another class, because your field is `public`), or you will get wrong results!

Comment: Great. Thank you for your help. I will take a stab at it, and let you know my results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the if codition

```
       if (bombBoard[d].equals("@") || bombBoard[e].equals("@"))
```

to

```
       if (bombBoard[d][e].equals("@"))
```

You are using 2D Array, and do  `array[i][j]` can populate its value for a gavin position.

Answer (score 0):

do you want to count from the whole array or certain parts of the array only?

From the code snippet you gave above, I can't really tell how you iterate the array since I'm not sure what is

```
bombBoard[bombRow].length  and  bombBoard[bombCol].length
```

But if you want to iterate the whole array, think you should just use:

```
for (int d = 0; d < 9; d++) // as you declared earlier, the size of array is 9
{
    for (int e = 0; e < 9; e++) // as you declared earlier, the size of array is 9
    {
        if (bombBoard[d][e].equals("@"))
        {
            maxTurns++;
        }
    }
}
```